# How check programmaticallly TEE support on Android?

Tags: android, security, android-security

How check programmaticallly TEE support on Android?

In a project we need check if TEE (Trusted Execution Environment) is supported in order to make a decision.

Regards.

Comment: What decision are you making?

Comment: In a high security context without TEE we wan't offer a weak authentication way.

Comment: Bit more detail about how you are authenticating would be useful. If you are utilising the KeyStore [Key Attestion](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation.html) gives you the info you require. See `teeEnforced`

Comment: Not only I want to know if there is a TEE support with the idea to redirect or not te user to diferets login mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Android 7.0 introduced this feature: [Key Attestation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation.html), which

> gives you more confidence that the keys you use in your app are stored in a device's hardware-backed keystore.

but not perfect since

> only a small number of devices running Android 7.0 (API level 24) support hardware-level key attestation; all other devices running Android 7.0 use software-level key attestation instead.

As  far as I know this feature will be mandatory for devices **shipped** , not updated with Android 8.0