# How to find out if an android device is using Trusty TEE security OS?

Tags: android, drm, mmc, ufs

I am new to Trusty TEE OS. Is there any way to find out if an Android Device uses such an OS without rooting the device ?

AFAIK there, DRM (Digital Rights Management) is the most widely used application of Trusty OS. Some examples for DRM frameworks are Widevine/PlayReady/ClearKey.

Does it mean that if any of these frameworks are present in the Android device, it is safe to assume that there is an underlying Trusty TEE OS in use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Widevine and PlayReady support multiple security levels - the most secure level for each is tied to the TEE but lower levels are typically not.

Hence, a simple check for DRM will not tell you if the device has TEE.

On older versions of Widevine you would determine the security level fairly easily which would give you a guide - I don't think you could take it as absolute:

- https://support.google.com/widevine/answer/6072714?hl=en

The same approach does not work for the current version of Widevine.

I don't believe there is a simple 'TEE supported' API - there are some tricks to try to determine - see the discussion in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64422042/334402

Comment: Thanks Mick, would you mind posting your answer here as well ? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233742/how-to-find-out-if-an-android-device-is-using-trusty-tee-security-os

Comment: @nishadkamdar - feel free to just copy it or link it as you want.

Comment: i have added a new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66170638/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-an-android-application-uses-trusted-execution-env pls check it out and let me know if you have any suggestions